# tryLock method - non-blocking method?

Tags: java, concurrency

The documentation of the `tryLock` method says that it is a non-blocking method
which allows you to obtain/acquire the lock (if that's possible at the time of calling  the method).

But I wonder: how can you obtain a lock and still guarantee at the same time that
your method (`tryLock`) is non-blocking?! Acquiring the lock implies that you're
trying to access a guarded section of code so it should block (if you're not lucky
i.e. you should block at least in certain scenarios). Could anyone explain the logic
behind this? Purely from a logical standpoint: I don't quite understand how this can
be done at all (guaranteeing that the method doesn't block). Unless they use another
thread of course within the code of the tryLock itself...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28%29

Comment: Well, on most modern CPUs this is done using CAS (Compare And Swap)

Comment: @fge Well, I mean: how is it done in Java? I tried looking into the code but I don't quite get it yet. Are you saying they're using native methods for this? I thought they do it with the "primitives" `wait`, `notify`, `notifyAll` only. But if so, then, logically... I just don't really see how it can be done.

Comment: I would suspect most JVMs do, yes (unverified, though, so don't take my word for it); probably not direct assembly code, but something like futexes on Linux can be used to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most implementations of these mechanisms use socalled CAS CPU instructions to do atomic actions based on a variable. CAS means Compare and Swap. These look at the value of a variable and if it is what you expect you change it. This provides a threadsafe (non blocking/locking) way to do comparison on data that is multithreaded.

A CAS instruction does the following atomically:

```
private int stored = 0;
public int compareAndSwap(int expectedValue , int newValue)

   if(expectedValue == stored)
       stored = newValue;

   return stored;
}
```

These non blocking mechanisms generally just retry the above function until it succeeds (the returned value is the expected value). Because the retry loop is very short the chances of a thread interrupting on each iteration are tiny (or in practice the OS scheduler will even make it impossible).

The actual java locks (`Lock` is just the interface they implement) are all much more complex because they offer extra features. But in essence the CAS mechanism is the base for most non-blocking threadsafe classes.

If you are interested in the inner workings of locking, [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) is a great source. Starting gently with what Java concurrency can do and advancing in how it does it. (it is a great source even for non java programmers). Your question is handled in chapter 15.

Comment: @monkjack Of course you are right, thanks. (note that some versions of the CAS also return a boolean to indicate change or not).

Answer (score 1):

> Acquiring the lock implies that you're trying to access a guarded section of code so it should block (if you're not lucky i.e. you should block at least in certain scenarios)

If that's the behaviour you want, you should just use the [`lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock()) method. The whole point of `tryLock` is that you use it when you *don't* want to block if the lock isn't available.

In terms of how that's *implemented*, it's up to individual implementations - so you should look at whichever implementation you're interested in. I would personally think it reasonable for those to use `synchronized` internally, if they knew that no user-specified code was ever run inside the `synchronized` blocks - in other words, it could block briefly for internal house-keeping, but not for the duration of the lock itself.

Or of course an implementation which had access to appropriate machine-level instructions could use compare-and-swap etc... heck, [`AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndSet-boolean-boolean-) could probably be used for a very simple version of this.

Comment: 1) "it could block briefly for internal house-keeping, but not for the duration of the lock itself" >>> this is what was sort of guessing too (so I wrote: "unless they use another
thread of course within the code of the tryLock itself"); 2) compareAndSet >>> OK, but then is this one itself non-blocking and if so, how is that one implemented... ?! I will research a bit. Thanks for pointing out some directions at least.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I wasn't thinking about using another thread in `tryLock`... it does sound like you should basically look at the implementation of the `Atomic*` classes, which may well rely on platform-specific machine code.

Comment: On 2) >>> Yes, OK, that one uses a native method: public final native boolean compareAndSwapInt on the Unsafe class.

Comment: I think I see now. Thanks. So it's done by native code. My question was whether it's possible to do that just by using the Java concurrency primitives like `wait`, `notify`, `notifyAll`. It sounded to me like it cannot be done unless tryLock itself is using a different thread (to do the check if the lock is free, block very briefly, and then if not lucky - to just not obtain lock and return in a non-blocking fashion).

Comment: @peter.petrov: Yes, you *can* do it like that, so long as you don't mind blocking *just for long enough to perform the housekeeping*. You wouldn't need a new thread for that - you could synchronize on a monitor which is only used for that housekeeping.