# tryLock() in a loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

`tryLock()` can fail to acquire lock. So if we use the return value to perform work we may not do the work at all.

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
boolean isLocked = lock.tryLock();

if (isLocked) {
    try {
        doWork();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

A `synchronized` would block until a lock is acquired, and so we know the `doWork()` will be done eventually.

So, is it right that we should `tryLock()` inside a loop until lock is acquired?

```
boolean isLocked = false;

while (!isLocked) {
    isLocked = lock.tryLock();
    Thread.sleep(100);
}

if (isLocked) {
    try {
        doWork();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should certainly not sleep if you got the lock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Almost never**, no.

If you *need* to get the lock, you simply use the `lock()` call. This will obtain it immediately it if it available, or wait if not. Repeatedly looping on `tryLock()` also has the *effect* of waiting for the lock if it is not available, but without allowing proper OS-controlled blocking and waking of the waiting thread. Instead the waiting thread will continue to occupy a CPU, burning CPU time and power, while waiting for the lock to be released.

In one of the worst cases<sup>2</sup>, the thread which owns the lock may be context switched out and waiting for an available CPU to continue, but the CPU is not available since it is being used by a thread busy looping on `tryLock`. It's almost form of temporary deadlock - temporary because eventually the `tryLock` thread will use its quantum and be scheduled off, but this whole process could take many orders of magnitude longer than the usual approach of using `lock()`.

All that to say that `tryLock()` has very limited uses. If you are using `tryLock()` in a tight loop, you are almost certainly doing something wrong. It is best used when you don't *really* need to get the lock and have other work you could do, and performance is important.

An example might be if you have to perform the same operation on several independent objects, each with their own lock. The default approach would simply be to `lock()` and `unlock()` each object in turn. An approach that might be faster would be to first `tryLock()` each object, updating any for which you get the lock (perhaps you do this more than once), and the returning to `lock()` any objects you missed the first time. By not initially waiting for any lock, and just continuing with the rest of the objects, you can probably achieve a higher update rate in a contended system.

Another case where `tryLock()` could be useful is when you can achieve the same effect in more than one way. Imagine for example some kind of "distributed counter"<sup>1</sup>, where you have one logical counter which is implemented as N separate equivalent counters each with their own lock. The *value* of the logical counter is simply the sum of the N underlying counters. To increment the counter (for example), you just need to increment any of the N counters. In this case, someone trying to update the counter can just `tryLock()` the underlying counters until he finds one that is "available" and modify it. This is likely to scale better than a single counter with a single lock.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, for a simple *counter* you would likely use atomic integers, such as `AtomicInteger` or, better, `LongAdder` - but for more complex structures this might be realistic.

<sup>2</sup> A worse scenario occurs if the `tryLock()` thread has a higher priority than the thread owning the lock, and the scheduling policy treats priorities strictly (i.e., a lower priority thread *never* preempts a higher priority one) like `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`. In that case, the higher-priority thread may spin *indefinitely* on `tryLock()`, since the lower priority thread which owns it will never wake due to the presence of a runnable higher priority thread. So you can even deadlock.

Comment: I understand. But this means `tryLock()` should only be used for `doWork` that may be ok to skip if lock is not available. That is my impression and i need a confirmation here. This is different from `lock()` that will get the lock eventually and therefore also the `doWork`.

Comment: Actually I see an interesting answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603051/8441607 - that `tryLock()` should be used only when obtaining a lock is optional. That more or less confirms this in addition to what @BeeOnRope said. Thanks.

Comment: @jforex78 - I updated by answer, to explain one scenario where you might use `tryLock()`. The usual case is exactly what you said: for one reason or another you don't _need_ to do the work, perhaps because you can do it later, or achieve the same effect in another way.

Comment: understood @BeeOnRope. thanks for confirming this. Accepted as Answer.

Comment: Note that even for equal-priority threads, preemptive task switching is not guaranteed by the JLS. However, in the OP’s code, there’s a `sleep` call. Still, looping `tryLock` makes no sense when we have `lock` for free. Might be worth noting that there’s also `tryLock` with timeout if needed.

Comment: This is the best answer I ever seen!

Answer (score 1):

`tryLock()` is for use in a thread that can do some *other* useful work at times when it is unable to acquire the lock:

```
while (there_still_is_work_to_be_done) {
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            doSomeWorkThatNeedsTheLockToBeLocked();
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    doSomeOtherUsefulWork();
    waitABit();
}
```